# Sort-Object by greatest numerical value value from Import-CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I want the greatest value (mailboxSize) at the top of the file. I have a cvs as inport.

When I do the following sort cmd:

```
Import-Csv import.csv| Sort-Object MailboxSize,DisplayName -Descending | Export-Csv SORT.csv
```

I get the following result:

```
"DisplayName","MailboxSize"

"persone6","9941"
"persone3","8484"
"persone1","7008"
"persone4","4322"
"persone5","3106"
"persone7","27536"
"persone10","24253"
"persone8","1961"
"persone9","17076"
"persone11","17012"
"persone2","15351"
"persone12","11795"
"persone14","1156"
"persone13","1008"
```

---

But I want this as a result!

```
"persone7","27536"
"persone10","24253"
"persone9","17076"
"persone11","17012"
"persone2","15351"
"persone12","11795"
"persone6","9941"
"persone3","8484"
"persone1","7008"
"persone4","4322"
"persone5","3106"
"persone14","1156"
"persone13","1008"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When importing a CSV-file, all properties are made `string`-type. You have to cast the `MailboxSize` to an `int` before you can sort it properly. Try:

```
Import-Csv import.csv |
Sort-Object {[int]$_.MailboxSize}, DisplayName -Descending |
Export-Csv SORT.csv
```

You should also use the `-NoTypeInformation` switch in `Export-CSV` to avoid the `#TYPE .....` line (first line in an exported CSV-file).

Sample:

```
$data = @"
    "DisplayName","MailboxSize"   
    "persone6","9941"
    "persone3","8484"
    "persone1","7008"
    "persone4","4322"
    "persone5","3106"
    "persone7","27536"
    "persone10","24253"
    "persone8","1961"
    "persone9","17076"
    "persone11","17012"
    "persone2","15351"
    "persone12","11795"
    "persone14","1156"
    "persone13","1008"
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$data |
Sort-Object {[int]$_.MailboxSize}, DisplayName -Descending |
Export-Csv SORT.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

SORT.csv

```
"DisplayName","MailboxSize"
"persone7","27536"
"persone10","24253"
"persone9","17076"
"persone11","17012"
"persone2","15351"
"persone12","11795"
"persone6","9941"
"persone3","8484"
"persone1","7008"
"persone4","4322"
"persone5","3106"
"persone8","1961"
"persone14","1156"
"persone13","1008"
```

I'm guessing the usernames are fake, but be aware that the same issue goes for `DisplayName` if your usernames actually was `personeXX` where XX is an int. Like:

```
persone7     27536
persone20    27536
persone13    27536
```

To sort them probably, you'd have to create a scriptblock for `Sort-Object` or create your own function to split the value and sort them correctly.